# How do I get full syncronization on "River Rescue"?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

No matter how fast I go following the path, I can never reach Terry before the bit by the waterfall.  But his log is always too far away to jump to without getting wet...is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was stuck with this as well, but then I followed below video and just jumped right before the waterfall into the water because the log was a bit too far away. Still got full synchronization.

Comment: Yeah, I finally realized that if you make it with perfect speed you can jump and reach the log and it counts.  You can't get attacked by any wolves or you won't make it in time, though!

Comment: I have to admit When I finally worked out how to do this I thought it was a bit of a cheat. I assumed "without getting wet" meant that you had to stay out of the water for the rescue so I kept trying to catch up to him when his log was stuck on something or similar. I felt quite cheated when I found a bit jump intot he water was actually the way to do it without getting wet. :(

Comment: @desaiw: I don't know. I considered some of the logs overhanging the river and getting to them and lowering a rope or something whcih would keep me dry...

Comment: "without getting wet" in Assassin's Creed games generally means "without swimming", I find. You can sometimes even wade through waist-deep water, but as long as Connor is walking and not swimming, you aren't "getting wet".